# Wget: Is there a way to pass username and password from a file?

Tags: password, wget, credentials, user-accounts

Is there a way to pass the username and password from a file instead of the command line via --user and --password?

Background: I want to run wget via cron and don't want the username/password show up in process view

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `.wgetrc` file ([GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Commands)) in which you can set username and passwords for either or both ftp and http.

To use the same credentials for both specify

```
user=casper
password=CasperPassword
```

or individually

```
ftp_user=casperftp
ftp_password=casperftppass
http_user=casperhttp
http_password=casperhttppass
```

Comment: The GNU [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Security-Considerations) also suggests using the `-i` option and feeding the username and password in from standard input.

Comment: Does `.wgetrc` provide the flexibility to work with more than one server? If not, `.netrc` is a better solution, see [the other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/671578/91715) from tobias.pal

Comment: I obviously missed wget using a `.netrc` file, but [it's documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Startup-File.html).

Answer (score 28):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the `.netrc` file. Create the file if it doesn't exists and set safe permissions:

```bash
touch ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Subsequently add the hostname, username and password with the `machine` `login` and `password` keywords:

```bash
echo 'machine example.com login casper password CasperPassword' >> ~/.netrc
```

If you then run `wget https://example.com` and the server responds with `401 Authorization Required`, `wget` will retry using the username and password from the `~/.netrc` file.

With `curl` it's needed to add the `--netrc` (or `--netrc-optional` or `--netrc-file`) parameter, because `curl` will not read the `.netrc` file without that.

When using this from cron, ensure that the correct `HOME` environment variable is set. Cron often defaults to `HOME=/` (in that case you would have to create the file as `/.netrc`, yet a better solution would be to set an appropriate `HOME` at the script's start, like `export HOME=/root`).

The `~/.netrc` file can be used for multiple hosts. More info about `.netrc` at [inetutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) and [curl manual](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc).

Comment: For the syntax of `.netrc`, see its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html), or the related [curl doc](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-netrc.html).

Comment: At first I'm too careless to see the `man netrc` in the OP, wondering WHY this works, then @ryenus your comment saves me, thanks~ Manual is always welcome :P
Then I know it's a rc file used by `ftp`, that is, it may not work for http. I'll try it on http later.

Comment: Quick update: _.netrc_ does work with wget and HTTP (at least on Ubuntu 18.04). Also related cURL doc was moved [here](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc).

Answer (score 2):

In many regards curl can be a better choice. Wget became a bit stale over time.

curl's -n switch can be used for this task:
 http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-n